# Trying to understand textbook sample solution - Fermat's little theorem / primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question**:

> Show that if $g$ is a primitive root modulus $p$ for an odd prime $p$,
>   then $g$ has no square root modulus $p$ (i.e., $x^2 \equiv g \bmod p$
>   has no solution)

**Sample solution of textbook**:

> Suppose that $x^2 \equiv g \bmod p$. Then $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ (by Fermat), contradicting $g$ being a
>   primitive root.

**However,** sample solution does not make sense. In fact,

$g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \bmod p$

$x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$

Hence, $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \not\equiv x^{p-1} \bmod p$

Am I correct?

Comment: That's exactly the contradiction that the solution is getting at

Comment: @bburGsamohT I don't understand, can you explain more.

Comment: After you assume something  false (at the start of a proof by contradiction) it is possible to conclude the proof by many different absurdities. You have simply found a slightly different path to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample solution doesn't rely on any intermediate value of $g^k$ before $k$ reaches $p\mathord-1$, only that $k=p\mathord-1$  is the *smallest* value of $k>0$ that  has $g^k\equiv 1 \bmod p$. That's the contradiction elicited by showing that, since $x^{p\mathord-1}\equiv 1$ and thus $(x^2)^{(p\mathord-1)/2}\equiv 1$ also, there cannot be a $g\equiv x^2$ for a primitive root $g$.